# Taggit django tags separated by a comma

Tags: python, django-taggit

I need to split string containing tags seperated by a comma to use in TaggIt, django.
However when using `split()` :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    tags = request.POST.get('tags_hidden').split(',')
    my_object.tags.add(tag for  tag in tags)
    ...
```

I run into an error:
`Cannot add <generator object view_name.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f3165109fc0> (<class 'generator'>). Expected <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'> or str.`

I found out the solution for this can be simply changing the code to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    tags = request.POST.get('tags_hidden').split(',')
    for tag in tags:
        excercise.tags.add(tag)
    ...
```

Why can't an inline expression be used here? Is there any other way I can use inline? Isn't both ways leads to iterate over list which contains only `str` types?